# in nuxt.js SSR i was created authentication system using laravel sactum im facing redirecting error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, laravel-8

nuxt.js I'm implemented an SSR authentication system using Laravel sanctum but I'm facing Redirecting issue.

When I have entered login credentials after summited my LOGIN button it Was not redirected to Dashboard it still on the login page if I need to visit Dashboard I need to manually enter the dashboard URL same thing on logout.

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'hello',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  router: {
    middleware: ['auth'],
  },

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/bootstrap
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',

    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
  ],

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {},

  auth: {
    strategies: {
      'laravelSanctum': {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000',
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: "/api/login"
          },
          logout: {
            url: "/api/logout"
          },
          user: {
            url: "/api/user"
          }
        },
        user: {
          property: false
        }
      }
    },

    redirect: {
      login: "/login",
      logout: "/",
      home: "/dashboard"
    }

  },

  // PWA module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
  pwa: {
    manifest: {
      lang: 'en'
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    babel: {
      plugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods', { loose: true }]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**middleware**

```js
export default ({ app, redirect }) => {
  if (app.$auth.loggedIn) {
    return redirect("/");
  }
};
```

**Login Page**

```html
<template>
  <b-container>
    <b-row>
      <b-col cols="6" class="mx-auto">
        <b-card title="Login">
          <b-button variant="primary" @click="login()">Login</b-button>
        </b-card>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  middleware: ["guest"],
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        email : "john@email.com",
       password : "123321"
      }
    };
  },

  methods: {
    login() {
      this.$auth
        .loginWith("laravelSanctum", {
          data: this.form
        })
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));     
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Layout **default**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <b-navbar type="dark" variant="dark">
         <b-navbar-brand href="/">NavBar</b-navbar-brand>
           <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
            <template v-if="$auth.loggedIn">
              <b-nav-item to="/dashboard">Dashboard</b-nav-item>
              <b-nav-item href="#" @click.prevent="logout()">Logout</b-nav-item>
            </template>
            <template v-else>
              <b-nav-item to="/login">Login</b-nav-item>
            </template>
          </b-navbar-nav>
      </b-navbar>
    </div>
    <Nuxt />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    async logout() {
      try {
        await this.$auth.logout();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Prefer using `@click="login"` rather than `@click="login()"`, otherwise, it will call the method during the render. Same goes for `logout()` etc... of course.

Answer (score 0):

`@nuxt/auth` do have a middleware for the auth already, you don't need to do it yourself.
To benefit of it, you can add this to your `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
router: {
  middleware: ['auth'],
},
```

In any `.vue` file that you want to whitelist (aka if you do not want to check if `loggedIn` is `true`), you can use the `auth` key

```html
<script>
export default {
  auth: false, // will bypass the middleware's verification
}
</script>
```

Everywhere else, it will double check that you're logged in before proceeding. Otherwise, it will bring you to the login page that you've specified.

Comment: thank you for your reply i tried with your answer but it not working  still having same problem

Comment: Do you have a github repo link?

Comment: i don't have  github repo link

Comment: Can you please make one? Will be hard to help you without any [repro] since for me, this solution is working fine.

Comment: i created github repo repo link https://github.com/ramur77/nuxt.js.git thank you

Comment: Do you have an URL for me to test the login since the backend is required. Also, please have a **FIXED** version of `@nuxt/auth` in your `package.json`.

Comment: this github repo contents backend + frontend https://github.com/ramur77/NUXT.git

Comment: Hm, it's actually a Laravel backend and I'm not sure that I want to spend hours figuring out how to install it locally on my machine. Do you have a remote hosted version somewhere, that I can just ping the URL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232261/discussion-between-user12380208-and-kissu).